# Is there a way to get the label of a value for an inputfield lookup in visualforce page?

Tags: visualforce, inputfield

I have a line that says:

```
<apex:inputField required="false" value="{!sobject[fieldName]}"/>
```

For a field that is a look up. In Salesforce, if the field is a look up the input field will also generate a look up to select the desired value. When the value is selected, I can easily get the selected Id, but is there a way to get the label as well? For example if the look up was to an account I could easily get the accountId, but I also want the account's name. Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: Do you need the Name value for use within the rendered page, or are you trying to have it in the page controller?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<apex:inputField required="false" value="{!sobject.fieldName}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't know the name of the sobject ahead of time, or perhaps even being user-selected, you need some controller code to assist you:

```
Id recordId = (Id)sobject.get(fieldName);
String recordName;
if(recordId != null) {
    String sobjectType = String.valueOf(recordId.getSobjectType());
    DescribeSobjectResult sdesc = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(sobjectType).getDescribe();
    DescribeFieldResult fdesc;
    for(SobjectField fieldToken: sdesc.fields.getmap().values()) {
        fdesc = fieldToken.getDescribe();
        if(fdesc.isNameField()) {
            break;
        }
    }
    Sobject queryRecord = Database.query('select '+fdesc.getName()+' from '+sobjectType+' where id = :recordId');
    recordName = (String)queryRecord.get(fdesc.getName());
}
```

Comment: Darn, I was hoping to not have to use describes. Is there an alternative since we already have the Name on the input at the time of selection?

Comment: The only other way to achieve this would be to use some JavaScript to grab the value from the lookup field directly and put it into a hidden variable that'd be accessible to the controller. This answer is the only guaranteed "Apex Code-only" answer, although you could hard-code a non-describe solution, it have to account for cases (because they use CaseNumber instead of Name as their name field) and probably several other objects.